# How do I change the opacity of an image using a for loop to create a gradual lighting up effect?

Tags: javascript, image, for-loop, event-handling, opacity

I have created a Css class which defines the opacity of my image but I need to access it in JavaScript and change it in a for loop then pass the new opacity back to a variable and repeat the process until I have the opacity I want which is 100%.

I need this to be triggered by the onmouseover event handler. Can anyone show me some code so I know how its done?

css in my external stylesheet:

```
.test{

opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// assuming jQuery
$('.test').bind({
 mouseover: function() {
  $(this).animate({opacity:1},500,function(){
    // something to do when done
  });
 }
});
```

Using straight forward javascript, you'll want to get the element:

```
var element = this;// for example or var element = document.getElementById('some-id');

var opacity = element.style.opacity;

function updateOpacity() {
  opacity = opacity+=0.2;
  if(opacity >= 1) {
    // done
    opacity = 1;
  } else {
    element.style.opacity = opacity; // this updates the opacity
    setTimeout(function(){updateOpacity();}, 50); // 50 is the delay, 50milliseconds
  }
}
```

Quick Note from the comments:

The setTimeout() call can be used in the following ways:

1. if you have NO parameters to pass, use this

   setTimeout(updateOpacity, 50);
2. if you are working with legacy code, you may find this, which works, but see below

   setTimeout("updateOpacity();", 50);
3. if you need to pass parameters to your callback function, use this in preference to 2.

   setTimeout(function(){
      updateOpacity();
   }, 50);

Comment: there's no need for the extra `function` wrapper in your `setTimeout` call.

Comment: No, do _not_ "quote the function name and parentheses"!  That's old style.  Just do `setTimeout(updateOpacity, 50);`

Comment: absolutely no quotes.  I'd fire any programmer working for me that did `setTimeout("updateOpacity()", 50)`

Comment: 1. it uses eval (bad) 2. it can only call functions from the global scope (also bad) 3. there's simply no need for it 4. w3fools.com

Comment: Great, thank you. It missed the obvious issue of having to pass parameters to inline function calls, hence my first reference to an inline anonymous function, enabling you to pass params.  You can't do that the way you mentioned, and using the second param doesn't work on IE, so you're left with the closure or quoted. e.g. try this without quotes or closures: setTimeout("alert('test');",2000); Can you recommend the non quoted or non-closure way?

Comment: @Alnitak, with that attitude I'd love to work for you, if only because of the excitement each day could provide... =b

Comment: @MyStream if you need to pass parameters, then use a closure.  If you don't need any parameters, just pass the function reference.

Comment: @DavidThomas I was (mostly) kidding, of course, but it does continue to amaze me how many people still think stuff like `setTimeout("doSomething()", t)` is the "right way".

Comment: @Alnitak - agreed :), and the above doesn't address the prefixes for different browsers - feel free to comment on that too.

Comment: @Alnitak, I agree (and I mostly learned JavaScript by *accident*, here on Stack Overflow). And I was only kidding a little...

Answer (score -2):

With jQuery you can use

`$('.test').fadeTo( 500, 1.0 ); //fade to 100% opaque in 500 ms`

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

For on mouseover:

```
$('.test').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo( 500, 1.0 );
});
```